# How to avoid re-using an existing SparkSession during ScalaTest runs

Tags: apache-spark, scalatest

I get the warning

```
 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; the static sql configurations will not take effect.
```

whenever I run tests which involve engaging a SparkSession.

I think this is because I use `SparkSession.builder.{_}.getOrCreate()`

with some options set in `{_}`.

I'm not sure what the warning is even indicating as surely `.getOrCreate()` necessitates there being a case where you are re-using (getting) an existing SparkSession?

It's not fatal but clogs my test logs.